# GemFire Cache expiration or eviction at a particular time of the day

Tags: spring-boot, caching, gemfire

I need to schedule my gemfire cache to expire the cache content in the region at a particular time in a day.I know there is a way using custom expiry tag in Client-cache.xml. But I not sure how to implement the scheduling logic in the Custom Expiry Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement and configure your own `CustomExpiry` class on the server region directly, the details are explained in [Configure Data Expiration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/developing/expiration/configuring_data_expiration.html). Considering that this needs to happen once per day and for every entry within a particular region, however, wouldn't it be better to just write a custom function and/or client to manually clear the region instead?.
Cheers.

Comment: I am using using PCC as a service.So I guess I wont be able to do much changes on the server side.What do you mean by client manually clearing the region?Is it possible,if yes how?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about **Pivotal Cloud Cache (PCC)** but _I believe_ you can actually deploy jars and change the configuration of your regions on server side (up to some degree), you might want to check directly with the vendor's [official support](https://pivotal.io/support). Regarding the client application, I mean exactly that: just a GemFire client app that executes a **region.clear()** once per day. You can find more details in [Region Management](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/basic_config/data_regions/managing_data_regions.html).